# What is the expected value of the number of random letters needed to produce my string.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, combinatorics-on-words

Consider the string $p$ with length = $n$.
Suppose we have the alphabet $\sum = (a_{1}..a_{k})$ and empty string $s$.
All symbols have equal probability of choosing ($p(a_{1})=...=p(a_{k})$). 
We could add any symbol from our alphabet to end of the string $s$. So my question is:

What is the expected value of the number of letters to be added to get our string $p$?

Comment: What exactly is your question? Do you mean the probability of obtaining the given string $p$ from randomly choosing $n$ characters from $\Sigma$?

Comment: Do you mean the expected value of the number of letters to be appended, in order for string $p$ to appear as a suffix (i.e., the expected first-occurrence time of $p$)? If so, one of the earliest solutions is by Nielsen, in the article [On the expected duration of a search for a fixed pattern in random data](http://orbit.dtu.dk/ws/files/4640102/PNielsen.pdf).

Comment: @DylanSp you're right , but not only $n$ characters ; my question about have no limits on quantity of characters

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, then @r.e.s's comment should lead you to the right data.

Comment: I've reworded the question to clarify what appears to be the intended meaning. @openspace -- please correct me if I've misunderstood! (FWIW, I've posted an answer to this presumed question.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a concise recursive version of the main theorem proved in [Nielsen's article](http://orbit.dtu.dk/ws/files/4640102/PNielsen.pdf).

Suppose $X=X_1X_2X_3\ldots$ is an infinite sequence of i.i.d. random letters from a finite alphabet $\Sigma$. Let $T_w$ denote the first-occurrence time of the word $w$ in the sequence $X$; i.e., $T_w$ is the least $t$ such that $w$ occurs as a subword in $X_1\ldots X_t$.

> **Theorem.** For any nonempty word $w\in\Sigma^*$,
>
> $$\mathbb{E}T_w=|\Sigma|^{|w|}+\mathbb{E}T_{w'}$$
>
> where $w'$ denotes the longest proper *prefix* of $w$ that's also a *suffix* of $w$, and by convention $\mathbb{E}T_\text{empty string} = 0$.

**NB**: Here the first-occurrence time of a word is taken to be the index of the *last* letter in that occurrence, whereas Nielsen takes it to be the index of the *first* letter in that occurrence.

**Example** (supposing letters $a,b\in\Sigma$)

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}T_{abaaba} &=|\Sigma|^6 + \mathbb{E}T_{aba}\\
&=|\Sigma|^6 + |\Sigma|^3 + \mathbb{E}T_{a}\\
&=|\Sigma|^6 + |\Sigma|^3 + |\Sigma|^1 + \mathbb{E}T_\text{empty string}\\
&= |\Sigma| \times(100101)_{|\Sigma|}
\end{align}
$$

E.g., taking $\Sigma=\{a,b\}$, this gives $\mathbb{E}T_{abaaba}=2^6+2^3+2^1=\color{blue}{74}$. Consistent with this, I ran $10^6$ simulations of $T_{abaaba}$ (using [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/)) and found a sample mean equal to $\color{blue}{74}.0$ with standard error $0.1$.