# Head-tails pairs

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, word-problem

A man is tossing infinite number of coins one by one. What is the average number of coins he must toss before he gets 4 consecutive head-tail pairs starting with heads?

Attempt- We need to find the expectation that of the number of coins we must toss before we get the sequence HTHTHTHT.

Comment: "Attempt" This is not an attempt. What are your attempts?

Comment: I could't really proceed after that.

Comment: Can you compute the expectation of the number of tosses needed to get the sequence HT?

Comment: By [this theorem](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1739989/16397), the expected number of tosses to get $HTHTHTHT$ is $2^8 + 2^4 + 2^2=276$ (hence $276 - 8=268$ tosses *before* getting that pattern).

Comment: @r.e.s. According to the paper, $HTHTHT$ is also a bifix and hence $2^6$ should also be considered in the sum. This brings the sum up to $340$ (which is a bit of a relief for me, in light of my answer!).

Comment: @Fimpellizieri - Thanks. I missed that bifix, so indeed we have $2^8+2^6+2^4+2^2 = 340$. (The OP needs to clarify whether he means this, or the number of tosses *preceding* the pattern ($340-8$).)

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot of 'notation' going on here but I hope it's self explanatory. Let $s$ be the sequence $HTHTHTHT$ and $X_s$ be the random variable that counts the number of tosses it takes to get $s$. Consider the following numbers:

\begin{align}
x&=\mathbb{E}(X_s)&&y=\mathbb{E}(X_s|\text{First tosses are T})\\
a&=\mathbb{E}(X_s|\text{First tosses are H})&&b=\mathbb{E}(X_s|\text{First tosses are HT})\\
c&=\mathbb{E}(X_s|\text{First tosses are HTH})&&d=\mathbb{E}(X_s|\text{First tosses are HTHT})\\
e&=\mathbb{E}(X_s|\text{First tosses are HTHTH})&&f=\mathbb{E}(X_s|\text{First tosses are HTHTHT})\\
g&=\mathbb{E}(X_s|\text{First tosses are HTHTHTH})&&h=\mathbb{E}(X_s|\text{First tosses are HTHTHTHT})
\end{align}

We wish to calculate $x$. To do so, we notice the following relations:

\begin{align}
x&=\frac12a+\frac12y&&&&y=1+x\\
a&=\frac12b+\frac12(1+a)&&&&b=\frac12c+\frac12(3+x)\\
c&=\frac12d+\frac12(3+a)&&&&d=\frac12e+\frac12(5+x)\\
e&=\frac12f+\frac12(5+a)&&&&f=\frac12g+\frac12(7+x)\\
g&=\frac12h+\frac12(7+a)&&&&h=8
\end{align}

Solving this system of linear equations we obtain that $x=340$.